# Including CLI scripts in composer packages

Tags: php, composer-php

i've got a composer package hosted at `http://github.com/danmatthews/req` that i'm attempting to include a CLI script with, using Composer's `bin` directive in `composer.php`.

The problem? My script is using Symfony's console component as a Dependency, and i *was* including Composer's autoload.php in order to pull those in. **But** when my package is included as part of another project, obviously the vendor folder is stored at the top level, not inside my package itself.

Is there something i can do to make sure that no matter where my `bin/req` script ends up (when installed with composer), that it will always load the dependencies it needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look how Behat is doing it here: https://github.com/Behat/Behat/blob/master/bin/behat

or Doctrine here: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/bin/doctrine.php

I noticed you're requiring Req class. I'd rather leave it up to an autoloader.

Comment: Thanks very much Jakub, it's essentially how i would have ended up doing it anyway.

Comment: I also agree with you on requiring the req class manually by the way.